# .NET Core WEB API System.Core.dll Reference Matching

Tags: .net, api, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, wep

I am new to .NET Core and trying to write a web service using .NET Core Web API in a project. The other sub projects are written in .NET Framework 4.5. 
   There is a project for Repository layer. I need to get all records by using repository in .NET Core Web API project. I added Repository project reference to .Net Core Web API project. So, for dependency injection; in Startup.cs ConfigureService sevent, I've added the following ;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(RepositoryBase<>));
}
```

I tried to list all records with the following method in the related controller;

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Book/GetAll")]
public IActionResult GetAllRecords()
{
    return Ok(_bookRepository.GetAll());
}
```

When I call this action via web browser, I got the following error message;

```
>  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The located assembly's manifest
> definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x80131040)   File name: 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>      at BookApi.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)   --- End of stack trace from previous location where
> exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
> services)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

Could you please help me about what it means? I've checked GAC dll with the following command ;

```
  C:\Windows\System32>gacutil /l | find /i "system.core"

>   System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL  
> System.Core.resources, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=tr,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL  
> System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL  
> System.Core.resources, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=tr,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

It seems like System.Core.dll with 4.0.0.0 version exists. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.2. Also, I am not sure if appsettings.json file contains the required declarations. Could you also explain appsettings.json format ?

Thanks for the replies..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check a few points.

- The file appsettings.json will not have this kind of declaration, You will have to check on your .csproj file.
- Why don't you simplify the DI by adding services.AddSingleton();
- Check all your dependencies and find which ones are using the System.core dependency and update them following the recommendation below.
- Update every dependency of your project at least to version 1.1.4+

I hope it works.